# Shell: How to add multiple new lines to the end of a text file

Tags: shell, text, newline, padding, text-processing

I have a shell script which makes sure all rows in the text file have equal length by padding 0s to shorter rows.

Before padding the lines, I want to add new lines to the ***end*** of the text file to make the number of lines equal to the max length of lines. For example, if the text file contains:

```
text
longerText
short
```

the output file should be:

```
text000000
longerText
short00000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

I tried to use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file) post's solutions, but could not make it work.

Here is my shell script which, however, adds new lines to the beginning of the file, not to the end.

```
#!/bin/bash

inputFile=~/home/vm/inputText
maxLength=$(awk '{print length($0)}' ${inputFile} | sort -nr | head -1)
numRows=$(wc -l < ${inputFile})

for (( i=numRows; i<=${maxLength}; i++ )); do
    #sed -i -e '$a\' ${inputFile}
    echo
done

while read -r; do
    printf "%s" "$REPLY"
    for (( i=1; i<=((${maxLength} - ${#REPLY})); i++ )); do
        printf "%s" "0"
    done
    printf "\n"
done < ${inputFile}

### To run
###./thisScript.sh > outputFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newlines are printing first because that's what your script is doing first. If you want the newlines at the end, move the FOR loop after your WHILE loop.

UPDATE: Then you can change your FOR loop to something like this. Note that you will have to create the pattern string dynamically

```
pattern="%05d\n"; #hard-coded to pad to 5 0s
for (( i=numRows; i<=${maxLength}; i++ )); do
    #sed -i -e '$a\' ${inputFile}
    printf $pattern
done
```

Comment: I tried it and it added new lines to the end like you said. But the new lines are not padded with zeros.

Comment: Changed the pattern to `pattern="%0${maxLength}d\n";` and it worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy with `awk`:

We read the file twice. In the first run, we find the max length by looking at each lines. In the second run we print the lines padding as necessary based on the max length. In the `END` block we print any filler lines to meet max length criteria.

#### Solution (left-padding)

```bash
awk '
NR==FNR {
    max = (max > length($0) ? max : length($0));
    next
}
{
    printf "%0*s\n", max, $0;
    next
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=(max-FNR); i++)
    printf "%0*s\n", max, "0"
}' file file
```

Output:

```
000000text
longerText
00000short
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

#### Right-padding

Right padding is not supported right off the bat, but you can roll your own solution.

```bash
awk '
NR==FNR {
    max = (max > length($0) ? max : length($0));
    next
}
{
    printf "%s%0*s\n", $0, max-length($0), (max-length($0)==0?"":"0");
    next
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=(max-FNR); i++)
    printf "%0*s\n", max, "0"
}' file file
```

Output:

```
text000000
longerText
short00000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

Comment: This was interesting. Is it possible to pad 0s after text, not before text? For example, instead of `000000text` be `text000000`.

Comment: I tried the updated script as well ang got this result: `text     0`

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan`. However, I tried the same exact code on MacOS, `awk version 20070501`, and it worked as you showed. I will try to see if I can fix your script to run on Ubuntu. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried `GNU Awk 3.1.8` on Ubuntu but got incorrect results again. Did you test your script on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Rlearner Yes, it worked fine on my GNU awk `3.1.7`. Try using `gawk` instead of `awk`. It might be that your default `awk` is pointing to `mawk`.